# JavaScript - How do I add a fade effect to a .src change

Tags: javascript

I want to either slide or fade the images.

How can I do this when I change the `src` attributes and use an array for my images?

You can watch the slider here:
http://www.chri126g.wigf1.sde.dk/Javascript/imageslider1/

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Ofcourse yes, but i am in alot of doubt on how to do this

Comment: You should create an example of your code here, not ask answerers to go off-site. You can flag The Reason's (and this) comment for obsolescence when you do.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is only tagged JavaScript, you can use jQuery in this situation:

```js
$("img")
  .fadeOut(500, function() {
    $("img").attr('src', imageURL);
  })
  .fadeIn(500);
```

Another way and a simple approach would be to use images as backgrounds and use `CSS` transition effects when you change the background:

```css
.your_elem{
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 300ms;
  -moz-transition: ease-in-out 300ms;
  -o-transition: ease-in-out 300ms;
  transition: ease-in-out 300ms;
}
```

Comment: No, you don't. You can use CSS animations.

Comment: Yes, or jQuery. What's wrong with my answer though? It's a solution. The user didn't tagged jQuery or CSS in the question. So this answer is valid.

Comment: *"you need to use jQuery in this situation"*. No you don't. And, since the question wasn't tagged with JQuery, a better answer would be one that doesn't use it.

Comment: Then you say he can use JavaScript for the animation?

Comment: I dont use jQuery :)

Comment: I would love to do a CSS animation but i just cant figure out how it would work when the .src attribute is changed :)

Comment: Maybe you can use background images instead of images themselves. That would be a better approach then you can easy make use of `CSS` animations.

Comment: Yes i updated the js with background image insted, it works perfectly for fading :) watch it here :) http://www.chri126g.wigf1.sde.dk/Javascript/imageslider1/

Comment: It does seem to "blink" when first loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate the img tag (one image is on the top, second image is in the middle - invisible at this time) and switch images opacity when the next img is loaded.
In the result you have 2 img tags and it's not super-clear, but it will be working well :)